# HackerRank - Candies

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, functional-programming, dynamic-programming

Here is the solution I've written for Hacker Rank [Candies](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/candies) challenge.
It uses dynamic programming (memoization in a boxed array).
I'm interested on what could be done to improve this code in term of style and performance (although it passes all the testcases of the challenge)
For example, I wonder if the bunch of guards I used could be made prettier

```
import System.IO
import Data.Array

main = do
    contents <- getContents
    print $ runTest contents

runTest :: String -> Int
runTest = sum . candies . map read . tail . lines

candies :: [Int] -> [Int]
candies rs = elems candies where
    go i 
        | n ==1 = 1
        | i == 1 = if (ri > riplus) then candies ! (2) + 1 else 1
        | i == n = if (ri > riminus) then candies ! (n - 1) + 1 else 1
        | ri > riminus  && ri > riplus = max (candies! (i-1)) (candies! (i+1)) + 1
        | ri > riminus = candies! (i-1) + 1
        | ri > riplus = candies! (i+1) + 1
        | otherwise = 1
        where
            ri = ratings!i
            riplus = ratings!(i+1)
            riminus = ratings!(i-1)
    ratings = listArray (1,n) rs
    candies = listArray (1,n) [go i | i <- [1..n]]
    n = length rs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using the trick of extending your array by one on both ends, ie. to include indices 0 and `n+1`, and assign:

```
ratings[0] = ratings[n+1] = 0
candies[0] = candies[n+1] = 0
```

and then `go 1` and `go n` will be handled by the other clauses.

Also, you can eliminate the boundary assignments in `go` with:

```
candies = listArray (0,n+1) $ [0] ++ [go i | i <- [1..n] ] ++ [0]
```

Finally you can use these definitions to make the guards more succinct:

```
go i | incL && incR  = 1 + max cL cR
     | incL          = 1 + cL
     | incR          = 1 + cR
     | otherwise     = 1
  where incL = (ratings!(i-1)) < (ratings!i)
        incR = (ratings!i) > (ratings(i+1))
        cL   = candies!(i-1)
        cR   = candies!(i+1)
```